# Dart - Access dynamically generated list

Tags: list, dart

I am trying to access a list I generated dynamically like this:

```
  var colors = new Iterable.generate(12, (i) => Colors.orange);
```

But when I use the index, for example colors[0], I get a "Tried calling " error. What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On a side-note: if the value generated does not depend on the index, we can more prettily use `(_) => Colors.orange` or, even better, use the `.filled` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Iterable` class does not have the `[]` operator to get values. Generate from a `List` instead. Example;

```
var colors = new List.generate(12, (i) => Colors.orange);
```